# Spring RequestMapping multiple paths, identify which one is being called?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

So I have a controller with `@RequestMapping(value = { "/something", "/otherThing" })`

I just can't seem to figure out how I can determine inside my controller as to which one of the paths are being served right now, "something" or the "otherThing".

Breaking down the controller and making 2 separate ones is not an option in my case.

Any ideas how I could go about determining the path being served inside a controller's method?

Comment: Why *exactly* is it not an option to decompose into two methods?

Comment: @chrylis Because I'm trying to create v2 of my REST API, and replicating the whole controller for one small change would clutter the codebase. I thought it would be vastly better to just handle the small logic change of v2 inside the same controller.

Comment: Spring MVC *is* just Java. All the normal tools of inheritance or two wrapper methods calling a shared service method are available.

Comment: @chrylis You are correct and that would be a normal way of going about it, but in my case it's someone else's codebase and I just wanna to make as little change as possible so I thought detecting the path and switching control flow on that would be much better than architectural change.

Comment: That might seem like a quicker solution for now, but over time avoiding the minor refactoring will make the code base more brittle. Refactoring in this case is a better change to make.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/something", "/otherThing" })
public void polymorpHandlerMethod(HttpServletRequest request) {
    if (request.getContextPath().startsWith("/something")) {
        // do stuff
    } else if (request.getContextPath().startsWith("/otherThing")) {
        // do more stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make two separate methods within the same controller, both delegating to the same method.

```
@RequestMapping("/something")
public void something() { 
    implementation("something");
}

@RequestMapping("/otherThing")
public void otherThing() { 
    implementation("otherThing");
}

private void implementation() {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the url using the below code and can get the path from it

```
URL url = new URL(request.getRequestURL().toString());
String path = url.getPath();
```

You can check this path and use it in your logic

Hope it will help your senario.

Comment: here request is HttpServletRequest